# DOMDocument node with boolean value

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

What is the correct way to extract a boolean value from an XML node? I have tried with this:

```
<?php
$xml = "<node><code>false</code></node>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$nodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('code');
if ($nodeList->length == 1) {
    if($nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue){
        echo 'VALID';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT VALID';
    }
}
?>
```

but I get `VALID` as a result.

Comment: type casting if((bool) $nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue)

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh `(bool)"false"` is __true__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nodeValue is going to return a string, so you need to do a string comparison. For example:

```
if($nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue != 'false'){
    echo 'VALID';
} else {
    echo 'NOT VALID';
}
```

You may also consider using `filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` to convert the value to boolean (for example it will also convert "1" or "yes" to a boolean), depending on the type of value you'll get in the XML.

Comment: Thanks. I should have var_dump-ed the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is no such thing as a 'boolean' value in XML it is all text. But you can use an Xpath expression to validate the value of a specific node and return it as an boolean directly:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<nodes>
  <node>
    <code>false</code>
  </node>
  <node>
    <code>true</code>
  </node>
</nodes>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//node') as $node) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('code = "true"', $node)
  );
}
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

An alternative would be to fetch the value as a string and use filter_var().

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//node') as $node) {
  var_dump(
    filter_var($xpath->evaluate('string(code)', $node), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
(  filter_var( $xmlNodeElement->current(), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE) ) ? echo "Valid" : echo "Not valid";
```

[Current when initialize, show first node element more about follow link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)